# PostgreSQL logical AND for finding two values in the substring

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, where-clause

I have a dataset with many text comments from a social media site. I want to find all instances where at least two country names are featured in the text. What I have right now looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE body ~* '(Canada|United States|Mexico)'
```

This lets me find instances of any mention of these three countries. But what if I want to find instances where at least two of these names are present.

Answer (score 1):

You could check each condition independently, convert the boolean results to integers, and ensure that the sum of matches is at least `2`:

```
 where ( 
       (body ilike '%Canada%')::int 
     + (body ilike '%United States%')::int
     + (body ilike '%Mexico%')::int
 ) >= 2
```

Of course this also work with regexes, although this might be less efficient than `like`:

```
 WHERE ( 
       (body ~* 'Canada')::int 
     + (body ~* 'United States')::int
     + (body ~* 'Mexico')::int
 ) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a separate comparison for each and add up the matches:

```
WHERE ( (body ~* 'Canada')::int + (body ~* 'United States')::int + (body ~* 'Mexico)::int) >= 2
```

However, it might be better to split the text and use array functions:

```
WHERE string_to_array(body, ' ') @> array['Canada', 'Mexico', 'United States']
```

Of course, the exact splitting logic depends on what `body` looks like.

Another fun method is a lateral join:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM comments c CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as num_matches
      FROM (VALUES ('Canada'), ('Mexico'), ('United States')) v(str)
      WHERE c.body ~* v.str  -- or use `like`
     ) x
WHERE num_matches >= 2;
```

Comment: Fantastic idea! Thanks.